# Internal MSBuild Error: Already registered for build-time

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

Tried to upgrade Visual Studio to 2015 Update 1 and it failed. Then started getting this error during my project build:

```
37>Unhandled Exception:MSB0001: Internal MSBuild Error: Already registered for build-time.
37>Error: MSB0001: Internal MSBuild Error: Already registered for build-time.
```

I thought it might be related to the Update 1, so I completely reinstalled Visual Studio. Nothing changed. I am able to build my solution (which has a mix of C# and F# projects) if I build the problem F# projects one at a time. But doing a rebuild on the entire solution gives me this error. Any idea where I can begin looking for answers? 

thanks

Comment: Well, after extensive trial and error I have figured out the following: this problem is only in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 1. Does not appear in professional (with or without Update 1) as well as enterprise pre-update 1. The problem seems to be specific to F# projects. Still looking

Comment: Lucky me! I get this error for VS 15.8 now. Looks like it's related to F#.

Comment: Yup! I got this error too, after upgrading to VS 15.8.0. Obviously an issue strongly related to F#. I'm going to file a report in https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/5504

Comment: fix is progressing, update posted ^

Comment: fix merged, [releasing in 15.8.5](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/5504#issuecomment-423315180)

Answer (score 8):

So I got this problem when upgrading VS 2017 to *version 15.8.0*, and googled my way to a workaround. Although initially reported for VS 2015, and probably caused by another bug at that time, I have a feeling several developers will land here in the next few days.

**A workaround is to set concurrent builds to 1.** This can be done in VS 2017 in Tools/Options/Projects and Solutions/Build and Run, and then you see it at the top in the settings pane.

[image]

This obviously will slow down many builds, but for some of us it's probably easier (or perhaps needed) to use this workaround rather than downgrade while we wait for a fix, which I guess won't be long.

Comment: Confirmed it works (believe it or not I was about to post this as a comment above but thankfully looked down) - doing a `Build|Batch Build` and selecting all your leaf projects without tweaking the concurrency also works (have not measured the perf - its very possible this facility inhibits concurrency)

Comment: Problem still in VS 2017 15.8.1

Comment: Probably won't be long until a fix is in place. You can follow the fix progress here: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/5504

Comment: there is another issue I can't locate which indicates its available in a nightly build alrready - I cant find it though :(

Comment: Sure you're not thinking of this same issue? The bottom post, from cartermp, says "Now that the fix is merged, users with the nightly builds can see it." I guess that means if you use nightly builds, you should have it if you update.

Comment: no somebody mentioned they were running on 16 cores - pretty sure it was a gitbuh issue and cited a nightly build version with a download link

Comment: Problem still in VS 2017 15.8.4. I suspect the fix will be in the next public release.

Comment: Finally fixed in 15.8.5.

Comment: Yay, yes: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/5504#issuecomment-423315180

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was with Modeling project. Unloading this project fixed the problem. I still believe there is something wrong with the build process, but that's not something I care to troubleshoot at this point. Hope this helps someone else